# Fetch Function Not Being Performing In Order | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, discord.js

**The summary:**

When I run this function, it runs once, skipping over my methods, and then runs again in the proper order.

**The code:**

```
function fetch_messages(searched_channel_id){
    client.channels.cache.get(game_log_channel).messages.fetch({ limit: 10 })
        .then(messages => {
            keys = Array.from(messages.keys());
            console.log(keys);
            for ( var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){
                console.log('iterating through messages');
                client.channels.cache.get(game_log_channel).messages.fetch(keys[i])
                    .then(msg => {
                        var msgContent = msg.content;
                        if (msgContent === undefined){
                            msgContent = 'undefined';
                            console.log('undefined message');
                        }
                        else if (msgContent.includes(searched_channel_id)){
                            console.log('channel record found in logs');
                            return [ msg, msgContent, msg.id ];
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    return 'not found';
};
```

**The console log:**

[image: console log]

**The problems:**

Main problem is the fact that it is occurring... is there any way to rewrite this which does not reproduce the error?

Secondary problem is why it occurs. I have not been able to find any documentation of this kind of thing happening and am curious as to the origin.

Comment: you are mixing `for loop` (sync code) with `.fetch` (async). So it will run all `                client.channels.cache.get(game_log_channel).messages.fetch(keys[i])` in parrallel and just print the one that response first and so so. If you want to `fetch(1)` then wait for response then `fetch(2)` use await instead

Comment: 'not found' is the second to last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about it. `fetch()` returns a promise. When you call the `fetch()` method, knowing that it's asynchronous, you're basically saying that

> `fetch` the message with the ID of `keys[i]` -- no matter how long it
> takes -- but please WHEN it's fetched (i.e. the promise is resolved),
> check if the fetched message's content includes the
> `searched_channel_id`. Cheers.

Notice the "WHEN" part. Anything inside the `then()` method is run after the `fetch` is resolved (an HTTP request is sent, data received, converted, etc.). You don't know how long it takes.

Anyway... as you're in a for loop, it's a bit different now. This time it's like

> I've got `keys.length` IDs. `fetch` me all these messages where the ID
> will be `keys[i]`. No matter how long it takes, but please WHEN a
> message is fetched, check if the fetched message's content includes
> the `searched_channel_id`. I know the order you start fetching them,
> and I can understand that it can take different times to finish getting
> the results back. You don't have to fetch one after the other as I
> don't really care the order you finish fetching them.

So, your code starts resolving these promises in the order of `key[0]`, `key[1]`, etc. but you can't control when it's finished without waiting for the previous ones to finish.

And then there is that `return 'not found'` at the end. That's like saying

> do these all I mentioned above but, you know what, I don't really care
> if you will found that message, let's just say it's not found. I'm too
> lazy to wait for you to finish all those. You can still finish the job
> I told you but meh...

You could update your code and use the [collection#find()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method to find an item where the given function returns a truthy value:

```js
async function findMessage(channelId) {
  const gameLogChannel = client.channels.cache.get(gameLogChannel);
  const logMessages = await gameLogChannel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 });

  const foundMessage = logMessages.find((msg) =>
    msg.content.includes(channelId),
  );

  return foundMessage || 'not found';
}

findMessage('98573472597130')
  .then(console.log);
```

I recommend you to watch ["What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf EU"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thank you very much for going in detail - as they say, teach a man to fish. Your solution worked elegantly.  :)